# Router which actually supports wake on internet

Tags: router, wake-on-lan

I am looking to a router (ADSL, Wireless N) which will support Wake On Wan/Internet (via a Magic packet from a computer external from the network)?

I do not mind if it has native support or has to be set up.

I have tried

- Linksys wag320n - does not work
- Netgear DG834DG - does not work

please can someone let me know of routers their have working (and possibly what you had to do to make it work)

Comment: why ? a router uses next to zero electricity.

Comment: unless you mean to wake a pc up on the lan, in which case do as robin suggests and log into the router remotely to a command line using something like dd-wrt firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is WoL normally uses your LAN's broadcast address to send the packets to all PC's on the LAN but only the PC with the relevant MAC address will be woken up.

A few sites mention using static ARP records - e.g. http://forums.smallnetbuilder.com/showthread.php?t=459
http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/95236-how-to-get-wake-on-lan-working-over-subnets

However when I had the need, I used an alternative method - to keep relevant MAC addresses noted, and then to log into the router local to the PC to be woken up and use that to send the WoL packets. I've successfully used Draytek Vigor 2800/2820/2910's and pfSense boxes for this purpose.